# Select a submatrix based on diagonal value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to select a submatrix of a numpy matrix based on whether the diagonal is less than some cutoff value. For example, given the matrix:

```
Test = array([[1,2,3,4,5],
              [2,3,4,5,6],
              [3,4,5,6,7],
              [4,5,6,7,8],
              [5,6,7,8,9]])
```

I want to select the rows and columns where the diagonal value is less than, say, 6. In this example, the diagonal values are sorted, so that I could just take Test[:3,:3], but in the general problem I want to solve this isn't the case.

The following snippet works:

```
def MatrixCut(M,Ecut):
    D = diag(M)
    indices = D<Ecut
    n = sum(indices)
    NewM = zeros((n,n),'d')
    ii = -1
    for i,ibool in enumerate(indices):
        if ibool:
            ii += 1
            jj = -1
            for j,jbool in enumerate(indices):
                if jbool:
                    jj += 1
                    NewM[ii,jj] = M[i,j]
    return NewM

print MatrixCut(Test,6)
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]]
```

However, this is fugly code, with all kinds of dangerous things like initializing the ii/jj indices to -1, which won't cause an error if somehow I get into the loop and take M[-1,-1].

Plus, there must be a numpythonic way of doing this. For a one-dimensional array, you could do:

```
D = diag(A)
A[D<Ecut]
```

But the analogous thing for a 2d array doesn't work:

```
D = diag(Test)
Test[D<6,D<6]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

Is there a good way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works when the diagonals are not sorted:

```
In [7]: Test = array([[1,2,3,4,5],
              [2,3,4,5,6],
              [3,4,5,6,7],
              [4,5,6,7,8],
              [5,6,7,8,9]])

In [8]: d = np.argwhere(np.diag(Test) < 6).squeeze()

In [9]: Test[d][:,d]
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Alternately, to use a single subscript call, you could do:

```
In [10]: d = np.argwhere(np.diag(Test) < 6)

In [11]: Test[d, d.flat]
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

### [UPDATE]: Explanation of the second form.

At first, it may be tempting to just try `Test[d, d]` but that will only extract elements from the diagonal of the array:

```
In [75]: Test[d, d]
Out[75]: 
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5]])
```

The problem is that `d` has shape (3, 1) so if we use `d` in both subscripts, the output array will have the same shape as `d`. The `d.flat` is equivalent to using `d.flatten()` or `d.ravel()` (except `flat` just returns an iterator instead of an array). The effect is that the result has shape (3,):

```
In [76]: d
Out[76]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [77]: d.flatten()
Out[77]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [79]: print d.shape, d.flatten().shape
(3, 1) (3,)
```

The reason `Test[d, d.flat]` works is because numpy's [general broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) cause the last dimension of `d` (which is 1) to be broadcast to the last (and only) dimension of `d.flat` (which is 3). Similarly, `d.flat` is broadcast to match the first dimension of `d`. The result is two (3,3) index arrays, which are equivalent to the following arrays `i` and `j`:

```
In [80]: dd = d.flatten()

In [81]: i = np.hstack((d, d, d)

In [82]: j = np.vstack((dd, dd, dd))

In [83]: print i
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]]

In [84]: print j
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

And just to make sure they work:

```
In [85]: Test[i, j]
Out[85]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Daddy likes! Can you explain the Test[d,d.flat] line?

Comment: @Rick Sure. I added a somewhat long-winded explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to solve your task is somewhat tricky

```
>>> Test[[[i] for i,x in enumerate(D<6) if x], D<6]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

possibly not the best one. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4257708/1265154) answer.
Or (thanks to @bogatron or  reminding me `argwhere`):

```
>>> Test[np.argwhere(D<6), D<6]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```