# Python Nested Loops to get a subcovariance matrix optimizations

Tags: python, matrix, nested-loops

I am trying to optimize a function that returns a subcovariance matrix from the full covariance matrix given the desired memmbers. The full covariance matrix could contains 500+ items and I could  be looking at a variable number of members each time but likely 20 or less per call.  This gets called 10,000+ times.

My code works but I was wondering how to optimize it.

```
def subcovar(covar,elements):
    numelements = elements.shape[0]
    subcovar = np.zeros((numelements,numelements))

    for i in range(0,numelements):
        for j in range(0,numelements):
            subcovar[i,j]= covar[elements[i],elements[j]]

    return subcovar
```

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use matrix slicing? [[offical python docs]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Here's a SO thread on building a sub-matrix by extracting arbitrary (ie non-sequential) rows and columns
[Slicing of a numpy 2d array, or how do I extract an mxm submatrix from an nxn array (n>m)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257394/slicing-of-a-numpy-2d-array-or-how-do-i-extract-an-mxm-submatrix-from-an-nxn-ar)

Comment: Thanks Mike.  It set me in the right direction.  I gave the full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mike's response I went back, looked at slicing and found the following:

Old way time =  0.016201255250881966  sec, choosing a 20x20 from a 500x500
New way time =  0.0016199544633708396 sec, choosing a 20x20 from a 500x500

10x faster

Old way time =  0.09903732167528723   sec, choosing a 50x50 from a 500x500
New way time =  0.00229222701258387   sec, choosing a 50x50 from a 500x500

43x faster

Old way time =  2.669313751708479    sec, choosing a 250x250 from a 500x500
New way time =  0.003080821529599664 sec, choosing a 250x250 from a 500x500

866x faster

## oldway

def subcovarold(covar,elements):

```
start2 = time.clock()

covar = np.arange(250000).reshape((500, 500))
elements = np.arange(0,500,25) # this is the elements to choose 
numelements = elements.shape[0]
subcovar= np.zeros((numelements,numelements))

for i in range(0,numelements):
    for j in range(0,numelements):
        subcovar[i,j]= covar[elements[i],elements[j]]

end2 = time.clock()
print ("time ", end2 - start2)

return subcovar
```

## newway

def subcovarnew(covar,elements):

```
start2 = time.clock()

covar = np.arange(250000).reshape((500, 500))
elements = np.arange(0,500,2)
msize = elements.shape[0]
ii = elements.reshape(msize,1)
jj = elements.reshape(1,msize)
subcovar = covar[ii,jj]

end2 = time.clock()
print ("time ", end2 - start2)
return subcovar
```

Thanks
Paul