# Processing a select range of values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 5x5 array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(5,5)
```

If i want to sum the entire array I can simply have:

```
np.sum(arr)
```

How would i go about summing the values in a box defined by the upper left corner (2,2) and lower right corner (4,3)?

If this isnt clear i would like to sum the bold x's in the below array:

X X X X X

X **X X** X X

X **X X** X X

X **X X** X X

X X X X X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use slicing like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(5,5)

# Top left 2*2 grid
np.sum(arr[:2, :2])
```

To sum the array in your diagram, use:

```
np.sum(arr[1:4, 1:3])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how the indices in your example `[1:4, 1:3]` are related to the 'coordinates' I want to use. I guess I dont know how this slicing works just yet.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4257708/3599580) is a great extension on this (correct) answer.