# Python Summation of Submatrix

Tags: python, matrix, logic

Just ran into this fun problem but I can't figure it out correctly

You have a matrix:

```
| 1 2 3 |
| 4 5 6 |
| 7 8 9 |
```

and your given two coordinates:

```
(1,1) and  (2,2)
```

find the corresponding submatrix:

so `(1,1)` and `(2,2)`

will create

```
|5 6|
|8 9|
```

my code:

```
def get_submatrix(matrix, coor):
    m = len(matrix)

    #chooses what rows
    lstart = coor[0][0]
    lend = coor[1][0]

    #chooses what columns
    estart = coor[0][1]
    eend = coor[1][1]
    subgrid = []
    print('coors: (%s, %s), (%s, %s) ' % (lstart, estart, lend, eend))
    #iterate through the matrices
    for i in range(lstart,lend+1):
    #    print('matrix index: %s' % i)
        print('matrix: %s' % matrix[i])
        row = matrix[i]
        subgrid.append(row[estart:len(row)])
        print('subgrid: %s' % subgrid)
    return subgrid
```

My code uses `len(row)` to pull the end of the row. which might work for some cases but not all cases.
Any help on crafting the for loop to obtain the submatrix?

Comment: how is this a summation of anything?

Comment: What *theorem*?

Comment: not suppose to be a summation, i thought i cleared all references from that before publishing. just trying to get the submatrix using the two coordinates.

Comment: Don't do this to yourself. Libs like `numpy` were written (also) to avoid brutal index massacres like this... have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257394/slicing-of-a-numpy-2d-array-or-how-do-i-extract-an-mxm-submatrix-from-an-nxn-ar

Comment: usually i agree but this was pulled from an interview question i had. libraries not allowed. if this was for some project and i asked on stackoverflow that would be fine. but this was posted for better logical thinking. i need more than just a library.