# Removing columns and rows from ndarray Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, multiple-columns, rows, slice, numpy-ndarray

I have implemented and algorithm to remove some columns and rows from an ndarray in Python 2.7, however I feel there should be a better way to do it. Probably I do not know how to do it well in Python, this is why I put the questions here. I have been searching but I have been not succesful finding similar questions and in the documentation (for example in [slicing and indexing documentation from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html))

Assume I have a ndarray with some rows and columns:

```
number_of_rows = 3
number_of_columns = 3
a = np.arange(number_of_rows*number_of_columns).reshape(number_of_rows,number_of_columns)
a
```

Which output is:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Let's supposse I want to remove some columns and/or rows of the previous ndarray. In particular I want to remove column 0 and row 1, this is an output like:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]])
```

To do that I follow the following steps, however they look too me not very elegant and I feel they should be a better implementation.

1. I select to columns and rows to remove, in this example:

   ```
   rows_to_remove = [1]
   columns_to_remove = [0]
   ```
2. Now I create a couple of list with the columns and rows to keep.

   ```
   rows_to_keep = list(set(range(0,a.shape[0]))-set(rows_to_remove))
   columns_to_keep = list(set(range(0,a.shape[1]))-set(columns_to_remove))
   ```

   This step in Matlab will be simpler just by using ~ to slice the indexes of the matrix (in python ndarray). **Is there a better way to do this?**.
3. Then I select those columns and rows to keep:

   ```
   a[rows_to_keep,:][:,columns_to_keep]
   ```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]])
```

Please note that if you just write:

```
a[rows_to_keep,columns_to_keep]
```

which output is:

```
array([1, 8])
```

This is a little bit socking for me, that `a[rows_to_keep,columns_to_keep]` is different to `a[rows_to_keep,:][:,columns_to_keep]`.
**Is there a better way to cover those steps?**

Thank you very much

Comment: For a slicing explanation: Slicing of a NumPy 2d array, or how do I extract an mxm submatrix from an nxn array (n>m)?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257394/slicing-of-a-numpy-2d-array-or-how-do-i-extract-an-mxm-submatrix-from-an-nxn-ar?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Question 2)**

Instead of :

```
a[rows_to_keep,:][:,columns_to_keep]
```

use:

```
a[np.ix_(rows_to_keep,columns_to_keep)].
```

This is called Advanced Indexing (see [Numpy documentation[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and [Writting in sub-ndarray of a ndarray in the most pythonian way. Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464015/writting-in-sub-ndarray-of-a-ndarray-in-the-most-pythonian-way-python-2)
)

For **Questions 1)** I will use Question 2 previous solution:
a) creation of a mask, there are more elegant ways to do it, for example see [Create a boolean mask from an array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.make_mask.html), but for simplicity:

```
mask = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=bool)
mask[rows_to_remove,:] = True
mask[:,columns_to_remove] = True
```

Now you can visualize:

```
a[~np.array(mask)]
```

Note now there is not need for Question 2) answer.

**Summary**:

```
mask = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=bool)
mask[rows_to_remove,:] = True
mask[:,columns_to_remove] = True 
a[~np.array(mask)]
```

If wanted you can reshape:

```
a[~np.array(mask)].reshape(a.shape[0]-len(rows_to_remove),a.shape[1]-len(columns_to_remove))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the delete method to get this done:
Using the array giving in your question as example. It would go like this:

```
number_of_rows = 3
number_of_columns = 3
a=np.arange(number_of_rows*number_of_columns).reshape(number_of_rows,number_of_columns)
b=np.delete(a,1,0)
b=np.delete(b,0,1)
```

And Voilà, b contains the output array, you want !!

Comment: Thanks. I should not do that for different reasons: a) the position is usefull to track back the data. b) later I want to use the whole matrix. Best wishes

Comment: You could put the positions of the rows and columns to delete in variables, before using the delete method. You could as well keep the original matrix !

Comment: True, but it is a big matrix and from the point of view of memory it can be ineficient.