# Extracting specific datas in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I get data from a specific row and column range?

For example, I have a 5X5 array. I would like to get data in row 1~3 and column 1~3?

I know there are other answers talking about getting data in columns, but I don't want the whole columns. Need help~

[image]

This is the coding I use to get the whole column.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array(np.random.random((5, 5)))
print(m)
#Getting column 1,2
print(m[:,[1, 2]])
#Getting column 1~3
print(m[:,1:4])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slicing of a NumPy 2d array, or how do I extract an mxm submatrix from an nxn array (n>m)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257394/slicing-of-a-numpy-2d-array-or-how-do-i-extract-an-mxm-submatrix-from-an-nxn-ar)

Comment: Have you read the NumPy docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slice in both dimensions at once:

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.array(np.random.random((5, 5)))
print(m[1:4,1:4])
[[0.92383161 0.76857191 0.39590632]
 [0.84968982 0.50103819 0.72481367]
 [0.2130214  0.61815567 0.55792883]]
```

Remember that python excludes the end-point of the slice, hence 1:4 instead of 1:3.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you do the same slicing with the rows as you do with the columns:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array(np.random.random((5, 5)))
print(m)
#Getting column 1,2
print(m[:,[1, 2]])
#Getting column 1~3
print(m[:,1:4])
#Getting rows 1~3 and columns 1~3
print(m[1:4,1:4])
```