# Assigning a matrix value to a variable or retrieving a value from a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to put values determined by matrix operations, thus in a matrix, as values in a separate function.

Essentially:

Matrix=[x,y]

I just need a way to get out the x and y values to use them.

Function=xsin(xt)+ycos(yt)

Comment: Are you trying to sub them in to solve the equation? How is `t` defined? Is `Function` a string?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want x and y from your matrix and assign them to a variable that you can use in your equation

```
Matrix = [10,11] # What is typically referred to as a list

x = Matrix[0]
y = Matrix[1]

print(x)
10
print(y)
11
```

If you actually have a matrix like with numpy then maybe the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257394/slicing-of-a-numpy-2d-array-or-how-do-i-extract-an-mxm-submatrix-from-an-nxn-ar) may be more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the `x` and `y` values from `Matrix`

```py
x = Matrix[0]
y = Matrix[1]
```

---

If you want to sub in those values:

```py
equation = "xsin(xt)+ycos(yt)"
Matrix = [2, 4]

equation = equation.replace("x", str(Matrix[0]))
equation = equation.replace("y", str(Matrix[1]))
```

```py
2sin(2t)+4cos(4t)
```

---

If you are trying to sub in the equations, you may like the `sympy` library

```py
import sympy

equation = "xsin(xt)+ycos(yt)"

# Needs to have * symbols
equation = "x*sin(x*t)+y*cos(y*t)"


def eq(matrix):
    in_dict = {
        "x": matrix[0],
        "y": matrix[1],
        "t": 1  # What is t?
    }

    subs = {sympy.symbols(key): item for key, item in in_dict.items()}
    ans = sympy.simplify(equation).evalf(subs=subs)

    return str(ans)


print(eq([1, 1]))
```

```py
1.38177329067604
```